# How to format xslt to indent in a specific way

Tags: xml, string, xslt, format, indentation

I need your help on an XSLT file as I'm fairly new to working with this kind of files to format XML.

As an input, I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-1.xsd">
<Description>
<MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
<OCRProcessing ID="IdOcr"><ocrProcessingStep><processingDateTime>2020-12-08</processingDateTime><processingSoftware><softwareCreator>ABCDE</softwareCreator><softwareName>ABCDE Engine</softwareName><softwareVersion>12</softwareVersion></processingSoftware></ocrProcessingStep></OCRProcessing>
</Description>
<Styles><TextStyle ID="font0" FONTFAMILY="Arial" FONTSIZE="10"/><TextStyle ID="font1" FONTFAMILY="Arial" FONTSIZE="11"/><TextStyle ID="font2" FONTFAMILY="Calibri" FONTSIZE="11"/><TextStyle ID="font3" FONTFAMILY="Cambria" FONTSIZE="11"/><TextStyle ID="font4" FONTFAMILY="Symbol" FONTSIZE="10"/><TextStyle ID="font5" FONTFAMILY="Symbol" FONTSIZE="11"/>
</Styles>
<Layout>
<Page ID="Page1" PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="1" HEIGHT="3508" WIDTH="2481">
<TopMargin HEIGHT="300" WIDTH="2481" VPOS="0" HPOS="0">
<TextBlock ID="Page1_Block1" HEIGHT="58" WIDTH="465" VPOS="150" HPOS="1008" LANG="en-US" STYLEREFS="font2">
<TextLine HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="453" VPOS="156" HPOS="1014"><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="LOREUM" HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="167" VPOS="156" HPOS="1014">LOREUM</String><SP HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="8" VPOS="156" HPOS="1182"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="IPSUM" HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="276" VPOS="156" HPOS="1191">IPSUM</String></TextLine>
</TextBlock>
</TopMargin>
<LeftMargin HEIGHT="2902" WIDTH="219" VPOS="300" HPOS="0">
</LeftMargin>
<RightMargin HEIGHT="2902" WIDTH="219" VPOS="300" HPOS="2262">
</RightMargin>
<BottomMargin HEIGHT="306" WIDTH="2481" VPOS="3202" HPOS="0">
<ComposedBlock ID="Page1_Block2" HEIGHT="58" WIDTH="1297" VPOS="3253" HPOS="965" TYPE="container">
<TextBlock ID="Page1_Block3" HEIGHT="51" WIDTH="410" VPOS="3259" HPOS="965" LANG="en-US" STYLEREFS="font2">
<TextLine HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="398" VPOS="3265" HPOS="971"><String STYLE="bold" STYLEREFS="font0" WC="1." CONTENT="dolor" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="146" VPOS="3265" HPOS="971">dolor</String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="9" VPOS="3265" HPOS="1118"/><String STYLE="bold" STYLEREFS="font0" WC="1." CONTENT="sit" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="241" VPOS="3265" HPOS="1128">sit</String></TextLine>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock ID="Page1_Block4" HEIGHT="58" WIDTH="141" VPOS="3253" HPOS="2121" LANG="en-US" STYLEREFS="font2">
<TextLine HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="129" VPOS="3259" HPOS="2127"><String STYLEREFS="font3" WC="1." CONTENT="Page" HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="94" VPOS="3259" HPOS="2127">Page</String><SP HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="8" VPOS="3259" HPOS="2222"/><String STYLEREFS="font3" WC="1." CONTENT="1" HEIGHT="46" WIDTH="25" VPOS="3259" HPOS="2231">1</String></TextLine>
</TextBlock></ComposedBlock><GraphicalElement ID="Page1_Block5" HEIGHT="14" WIDTH="2044" VPOS="3228" HPOS="218"/><GraphicalElement ID="Page1_Block6" HEIGHT="4" WIDTH="2044" VPOS="3244" HPOS="218"/>
</BottomMargin>
<PrintSpace HEIGHT="2902" WIDTH="2043" VPOS="300" HPOS="219">
<TextBlock ID="Page1_Block7" HEIGHT="124" WIDTH="898" VPOS="303" HPOS="791" LANG="en-US" STYLEREFS="font0">
<TextLine HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="886" VPOS="309" HPOS="797"><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="amet" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="183" VPOS="309" HPOS="797">amet</String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="9" VPOS="309" HPOS="981"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="consectetur " HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="236" VPOS="309" HPOS="991">consectetur </String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="309" HPOS="1228"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="adipiscing " HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="58" VPOS="309" HPOS="1239">adipiscing </String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="309" HPOS="1298"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="elit" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="374" VPOS="309" HPOS="1309">elit</String></TextLine>
<TextLine HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="252" VPOS="382" HPOS="1108"><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="Aliquam " HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="203" VPOS="382" HPOS="1108">Aliquam </String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="382" HPOS="1312"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="eu" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="37" VPOS="382" HPOS="1323">eu</String></TextLine>
</TextBlock>
</PrintSpace>
</Page>
</Layout>
</alto>
```

I'm trying to apply several things to it, but my main issue is that I would like to have my **textline**tags contain **string** and **sp** tags on only one *line* with no indentation. For my **textline** tags, as an example, I have this as an output :

```
<TextLine/>
            <String STYLE="bold"
                    WC="1."
                    CONTENT="amet"
                    HEIGHT="39"
                    WIDTH="183"
                    VPOS="309"
                    HPOS="797">amet</String>
            <String STYLE="bold"
                    WC="1."
                    CONTENT="consectetur "
                    HEIGHT="39"
                    WIDTH="236"
                    VPOS="309"
                    HPOS="991">consectetur </String>
            <String STYLE="bold"
                    WC="1."
                    CONTENT="adipiscing "
                    HEIGHT="39"
                    WIDTH="58"
                    VPOS="309"
                    HPOS="1239">adipiscing </String>
            <String STYLE="bold"
                    WC="1."
                    CONTENT="elit"
                    HEIGHT="39"
                    WIDTH="374"
                    VPOS="309"
                    HPOS="1309">elit</String>
            <SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="9" VPOS="309" HPOS="981"/>
            <SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="309" HPOS="1228"/>
            <SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="309" HPOS="1298"/>
         </TextLine>
```

And I want this:

```
<TextLine/> <String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="amet" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="183" VPOS="309" HPOS="797">amet</String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="9" VPOS="309" HPOS="981"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="consectetur " HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="236" VPOS="309" HPOS="991">consectetur </String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="309" HPOS="1228"/><String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="adipiscing " HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="58" VPOS="309" HPOS="1239">adipiscing </String><SP HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="10" VPOS="309" HPOS="1298"/> <String STYLE="bold" WC="1." CONTENT="elit" HEIGHT="39" WIDTH="374" VPOS="309" HPOS="1309">elit</String> </TextLine>
```

Would you know what I'm supposed to modify/delete/add in *this* xsl to achieve this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" >

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="TextBlock-by-LANG" match="//tns:TextBlock" use="@LANG" />
    <xsl:variable name="lang">
        <xsl:for-each select="//tns:TextBlock">
            <xsl:sort select="count(key('TextBlock-by-LANG', @LANG))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@LANG"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <alto>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//tns:Description"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//tns:Styles"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//tns:Page">
                <xsl:sort select="@PHYSICAL_IMG_NR" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </alto>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tns:Description">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tns:Styles">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tns:Page">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:PrintSpace//tns:TextBlock">
                <xsl:sort select="@VPOS" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="@HPOS" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="tns:TextBlock">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:TextLine">
                <xsl:sort select="@VPOS" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:sort select="@HPOS" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:template match="tns:TextLine">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:String"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:SP"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="tns:String">
        <xsl:copy select=".">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@CONTENT"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tns:SP">
        <xsl:copy select=".">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@CONTENT"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you a lot for all your help and advices

Comment: Well, saying you get a self-closed `<TextLine/>` but then an indentation on the next line doesn't make any sense to me. On the other hand the attribute indentation looks like a Saxon feature, so perhaps, use `version="3.0"` on the XSLT and then `<xsl:output indent="yes" suppress-indentation="TextLine"/>`. That assumes your tool has Saxon 9 or 10 under the hood and supports that output property.

Comment: I overlooked the use of a namespace so `suppress-indentation="TextLine"` can't work, you would need `suppress-indentation="tns:TextLine"`.

Comment: This definitely solved the problem of indentation. Thank you a lot

Would you know how to get within text line the format?
<textline> string sp string sp string </textline>
Like in the input and to avoid getting:
<textline> string string string sp sp sp </textline>

Comment: Consider to ask other issues in a separate question where you show the details inside the question with clear markdown and formatting to allow us to understand what you want to achieve and where it fails. Trying to figure from the "mess" that is a unformatted comment on StackOverflow how some indentation is supposed to work is rather too tedious.

Comment: I understand, thank you a lot for your advices.
I will create another post for this problem

Comment: Note that the effect of `indent="yes"` in XSLT is pretty much implementation-defined (the spec just says, add whitespace to make it human-readable), so if you're going to ask questions about it you need to say which XSLT processor you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown formatting might be caused by using Saxon 9 or 10 under the hood so using XSLT 3 or 2 and e.g. `<xsl:output indent="yes" suppress-indentation="tns:TextLine"/>` should help to not indent the contents of `TextLine` elements in the tns namespace.